# Horizontal Scrollbar for TreeView not working in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

I'm creating a system that registers data in a sqlite database. When the system starts, it calls the "def show()" function, which loads all data from the database and generates a Treeview.

I created a horizontal and a vertical Scrollbar. Horizontal Scrollbar is not working.

I created the "list" variable inside the function to simulate the return of a database query.
When the "def show()" function is called, it generates a Treeview with data from the "list" variable.

Horizontal Scrollbar is not working. Could you help me solve it, please?

The code is the following (in Github):

[GitHub Code Link](https://github.com/alexandrepalmag/TkinterSistema/blob/master/main.py)

I've tried several paths with no solution.

How can I make the horizontal Scrollbar work?

Comment: line 2
    from cgitb import text
DeprecationWarning: 'cgitb' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13. I am using 3.12.0rc1. Where did u see "def show()"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mre] in your question here on StackOverflow. You should also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your treeview is larger than the window.

To get the scrollbars, you need to make the treeview adjust it's width and height to the window.

Add these lines after the relevant widgets are created.

```
janela.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
janela.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame_direita.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Gprime, I followed your guidance and the problem was solved.
Thanks a lot for the help!